# Trying to get behaviour of keras dense input shape and ndarrays

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, keras

I'm trying to fit my simple keras model for 5-classes classification:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_shape=(6,), activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(5, activation="softmax"))
```

Also, I have the data with format:

```
>print(features)
[array([155,  22, 159,  57, 247,  88], dtype=uint8),
 array([184, 165, 127,  49, 190,  0,], dtype=uint8),
 ...
 array([35, 136,   32, 255, 114, 137], dtype=uint8)]
```

But when I'm trying to fit the model, I'm getting the next error:

```
Error when checking input: expected input_layer_input to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

I can't understand what is the reason oh this error. Could you please help me to get it?

Some additional information:

```
>type(features)
numpy.ndarray

>features.shape
(108885,)

>type(features[0])
numpy.ndarray

>features[0].shape
(6,)
```

Comment: Can you post fitting code?

Comment: Your input data should have shape (108885, 6) in order to work with keras. you have to make a single array, not an array of arrays.

Comment: @adityathakkar yes, ofc: `model.fit(features, one_hot_labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the input data to be a 2 Dimensional (numpy) array, or you could just change the input_shape to (1,), depending on what you want to do. Rightnow you have an array of arrays. Keras dosn't accept that.

Comment: Great! I've just made `features = np.vstack(features)` to make 2-d array instead of array of arrays and got shape `(108885, 6)` and now it works. Thanks!